# Data plotting: problem with coloring the plots

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a data to plot in the form of {x,y,f(x,y)}. Essentially, I have two curves (to be precise, surfaces). I want different colors for each surface. But I'm failing to do so.

Here is my [datatoplot](https://pastebin.com/FePqRtb9):

```
Graphics3D[Riffle[{Red, Blue},Point /@ Transpose[SortBy[Last] /@ Partition[datatoplot, 2]]]]
```

In the above plot: you see four surfaces. Actually there is a periodic boundary condition (all the faces of cuboid). So, from left corner (first red) and third (blue red combination) are the same, likewise second (blue red) and forth (blue).

PS: To be more clear. The top face and the bottom face are same. Likewise, any opposite face of the cuboid. So, the first red (on the left corner) goes and reappear on the top ( third surface) but blue and red (instead of red). Hope it's clear! But I can do it better, if it isn't

I was looking for the clever way to color them. But I don't know.

[image]

Comment: Very cool dataset. But I see 4 surfaces.

Comment: @AntonAntonov Oops! Thanks for pointing it out. Actually there is a periodic boundary condition. So, from left corner (first red) and third (blue red combination) are the same, likewise second (blue red) and forth (blue).

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Is the plot in my answer something you expect/want?

Comment: @AntonAntonov. I'm sorry, maybe I'm talking in telepathy. You almost got it. I mean the top face and the bottom face are same. Likewise, any opposite face of the cuboid. So, the first red (on the left corner) goes and reappear on the top ( third surface) but blue and red (instead of red). Hope it's clear! But I can do it better, if it isn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** We find the Nearest Neighbors (NN's) graph based on the 4 closest NN's for each point.

**2.** We find the connected components of that graph.

**3.** We plot the components with some color scheme/function.

```
data = Import["~/Downloads/FePqRtb9.m"];

AbsoluteTiming[
 gr = NearestNeighborGraph[data, 4];
 ccs = ConnectedComponents[gr];
]
Length[ccs]

(* {0.110175, Null} *)
(* 4 *)  

Graphics3D[
 MapIndexed[{ColorData[7, "ColorList"][[#2[[1]]]], Point[#1]} &, ccs]]
```

[image]

I used the 4 closest Nearest Neighbors (NN's) for each point because the points patterns of the surfaces can be projected on 2D regular grids. I could have used 8 NN's, but 4 NN's seemed enough (i.e. it worked.) Because we have 4 surfaces I used 4 as the number of connected components to be identified.

### Additional code / responses

Using this code we can see which surface on the plot corresponds to which element of components lists, `ccs`.

```
Graphics3D[
 MapIndexed[{Text[
     Style["Surface:" <> ToString[#2[[1]]], Blue, Bold, 
      FontSize -> 16], Mean[#1]], 
    ColorData[7, "ColorList"][[#2[[1]]]], Point[#1]} &, ccs]]
```

[image]

And we have this plot for those components:

```
Graphics3D[
 MapIndexed[{Text[
     Style["Surface:" <> ToString[#2[[1]]], Blue, Bold, 
      FontSize -> 16], Mean[#1]], 
    ColorData[7, "ColorList"][[#2[[1]]]], Point[#1]} &, 
  ccs[[{1, 3}]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: I edited my question. Unfortunately, I was explaining to myself (I.e too vague in my explanation). But you almost got it! I need two days sets (containing two surfaces data), that will solve all the hurdles. I need to calculate quantities but this separation of data wasn't clear before so everything was wrong like the plot, as shown in the question

Comment: I hope you can modify / extend the code of my answer to produce the plot you want...

Comment: I believe I can :) 4 closest neighbors because of 4 curves, so 4 sets? And maybe a little word about the first two (nearest neighbor and connected components part) would pave a great way for deeper understanding :) many thanks for your valuable time

Comment: I updated my answer with more explanations.

Comment: Thanks @Anton. Just a last question (very very important, only experts like you can help), I'm ignorant in these tech. When I chose 2 for nearest neighbor however, I got the same result. I'm surely missing something.
That's why I'm not able to get two sets for two surfaces? This is kind very important for the work.

Comment: I edited my question, also. Just to make it very clear. I need data set only for surface 1 and another for surface 2. Do you think is doable?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Just impressive! sorry it took time to implement. I could do all what I want now, many thanks to you.

Comment: Sounds good, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can experiment with [`ListLinePlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot3D.html).

```
ListPointPlot3D[datatoplot, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[z]], 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.002], ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]